# Use of dynamic array in ActionScript?

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, actionscript

I would like to have a dynamic array depending on values inputted by the user. How can I go about doing that?

Would array1.push(i++) work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, you can push anything to an array in ActionScript 3, it's dynamic in nature.

```
var array1:Array = [];
for(var i:int = 0; i < 50; i++)
    array1.push(i++);
```

would work fine, and result in:

```
0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22,24,26,28,30,32,34,36,38,40,42,44,46,48
```

Comment: Would push work for an unlimited number on values though? The limit of i would depend on how many values the user has entered

Comment: Yes, the Array class in ActionScript 3 has no fixed length. You can push unlimited elements of any type. If you want a fixed length object, look at the Vector class.